# Vbscript list all PDF files in folder and subfolders

Tags: vbscript, directory, subdirectory, directory-listing

Well here is my code but I just can not filter the listing using the objFile.Extension i am sure it is some thing silly

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\dev"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
If objFile.Extension = "PDF" Then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
Next
Wscript.Echo

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
        Next
        Wscript.Echo
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

On run it comes back with the error

> (11, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this
>   property or method: 'objFile.Extension'

Answer (score 24):

You'll want to use the [GetExtensionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0fxha2a%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method on the FileSystemObject object.

```
Set x = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
WScript.Echo x.GetExtensionName("foo.pdf")
```

In your example, try using this

```
For Each objFile in colFiles
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "PDF" Then
        Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks John that did it 

but I am having problems trying to filter the subfolders I am not having much luck

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you getting errors or something else?

Answer (score 11):

(For those who stumble upon this from your search engine of choice)

This just recursively traces down the folder, so you don't need to duplicate your code twice. Also the OPs logic is needlessly complex.

```
Wscript.Echo "begin."
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSuperFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments(0))
Call ShowSubfolders (objSuperFolder)

Wscript.Echo "end."

WScript.Quit 0

Sub ShowSubFolders(fFolder)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "PDF" Then
            Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
        End If
    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolders(Subfolder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The file extension may be case sentive...but the code works.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  objStartFolder = "C:\Dev\"

  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
  Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path

  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

  For Each objFile in colFiles
  strFileName = objFile.Name

  If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "pdf" Then
      Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
  End If

  Next
  Wscript.Echo

  ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

  Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
     For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
          Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
          Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
          Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
          For Each objFile in colFiles
              Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
          Next
          Wscript.Echo
          ShowSubFolders Subfolder
      Next
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\NOLA BOOTHE\My Documents\operating system"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

May not help OP, but hopefully others may find this helpful:

run

```
%ComSpec% /c cd/d StartPath & dir/s/b *.pdf
```

using shell object

StdOut will contain all PDF files

Comment: How do I find out who downvoted this? Would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

There's a well documented answer to your question at this url:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/18/how-can-i-list-the-files-in-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders.aspx

The answer shown at that URL is kind of complicated and uses WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to iterate through files and folders.  But if you do a lot of Windows administration, it's worth the effort to learn WMI.

I'm posting this now in case you need something right now; but I think I used to use a filesystemobject based approach, and I'll look for some example, and I'll post it later if I find it.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code :

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

objStartFolder = "C:\Folder1\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles 
    strFileName = objFile.Name

    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "pdf" Then 
        Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
    End If
Next

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders 
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path) 
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
        for each Files in colFiles 
            if LCase(InStr(1,Files, ".pdf")) > 1 then Wscript.Echo Files 
        next
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder 
    Next 
End Sub
```