# Getting information from multiple excel files

Tags: excel

So you have two directories ../main/sub1 and ../main/sub2

The main excel file is in main and I want to get information from all the excel files in sub1 and in sub2, but I do not know the names of these files, would it be possible to make a formula that would basically do this a1+a2 for every file and combine them all together in one cell?

Sorry of my explanation is poor. Also anyone have any good resources for learning excel and multiple files, thanks.

edit: Basically a lot like this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-another-workbook-to-your-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5 but more dynamically

Comment: Yes and No, you can create VBA code to make it happen, but there is no build-in function to do that.  And this question is too broad if you tag as VBA, consider to do some research and tried it yourself first.

Comment: You might want to start with how to find all the file names in a folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200028/vbscript-list-all-pdf-files-in-folder-and-subfolders